# Replace a string containing the '&' character

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Using `phpmyadmin` and `mysql` I need to select records containing the string '&pageid=page' in order to replace it with a null string.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` where post_content like '%&pageid=page%'
```

but no record was selected.
I tried again with without the `&` like explained below

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` where post_content like '%pageid=page%'
```

and it worked, so I had some records selected. At this point, I suppose that the '&' char must be handled in a different way. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: `like '%\&pageid=page%'`

Comment: SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` where post_content like '%\&pageid=page%' had no effect ... still no record selected

Comment: the & character should not be handled in a different way, see it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3febe0/1 - are you sure you have records that contain the exact string `&pageid=page` ?

Comment: Are you sure it is stored in table as `&` not as `&amp;`

Comment: hi .. unluckily yes, i'm sure ... many links doesn't work and yes, i have them stored as & and not as &amp; ... thnx

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword **escape** to mention escape character for the query.

```
 select stuff from mytab
  where
    mycol like '%\_to\_%' escape '\';
```